# Events not creating for multiple users at same call for the application permission

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have registered the App with application permission in Azure Directory and I am able to get Token and schedule a event by using the Same token for the single User at a time, but when I add the multiple Attendees (vinay@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com,AdeleV@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com) in the list then it's not creating the meeting for another user which I have not mentioned in the

```
GraphServiceClient(accessToken).Users["AdeleV@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com"].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
```

and am receiving the email saying
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
Vinay@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com
Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.

and I also got Some Error in the mail for

Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: SA0PR19MB4602.namprd19.prod.outlook.com

Vinay@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com
Remote Server returned '550 5.7.501 Service unavailable. Spam abuse detected from IP range. For more information please go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=526653. S(2017052602) [BYAPR19MB3063.namprd19.prod.outlook.com]'

Original message headers:

```
Received: from SA0PR19MB4602.namprd19.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::d4d8:a608:e081:3249]) by SA0PR19MB4602.namprd19.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::d4d8:a608:e081:3249%7]) with mapi id 15.20.5373.018; Tue, 28 Jun 2022
 13:43:23 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2022 13:43:23 +0000
Message-ID:
    <SA0PR19MB4602896A05ED8C22B925567688B89@SA0PR19MB4602.namprd19.prod.outlook.com>
Subject: Schedule From .Net
```

Code

```
public static async Task<Event> CreateEvent(string accessToken)
        {
            Event event1 = new Event();
            var @event = new Event
            {
                Subject = "Schedule From .Net",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = "Test Schedule"
                },
                Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
                {
                    DateTime = "2022-07-10T12:00:00",
                    TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                End = new DateTimeTimeZone
                {
                    DateTime = "2022-07-10T14:00:00",
                    TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                Location = new Location
                {
                    DisplayName = "OR1"
                },
                Attendees = new List<Attendee>()
                    {
                        new Attendee
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = "vinay@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com",
                                Name = "Vinay"
                            },
                            Type = AttendeeType.Required
                        },
                        new Attendee
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = "AdeleV@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com",
                                Name = "Adelev"
                            },
                            Type = AttendeeType.Required
                        }
                    },
                TransactionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            };

            try
            {
                event1 = await GraphServiceClient(accessToken).Users["AdeleV@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com"].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return event1;
        }
```

Can anybody can you please check and suggest how we can schedule for multiple users at thee same time by using the same.

is there any option to change below code to add multiple emails in Users[] array

```
GraphServiceClient(accessToken).Users["AdeleV@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com"].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
```

to

```
GraphServiceClient(accessToken).Users["AdeleV@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com,AdeleV@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com"].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
```

but this gives error as below

```
Code: ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource could not be discovered.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2022-06-28T14:41:33
    request-id: 41cf2d89-de6d-44df-b42f-1e11d2fe430e
    client-request-id: 41cf2d89-de6d-44df-b42f-1e11d2fe430e
ClientRequestId: 41cf2d89-de6d-44df-b42f-1e11d2fe430e
```

can please suggest which way we have to call

Regards
Srikanth

Comment: Your code should work if your `GraphServiceClient` is authenticated well. Per my understanding, your requirement is that you need to create an event and let several users to join, pls note that this doesn't mean you need to all the user ids into `.Users["id1, id2, id3"]`, `.Users["userId"]` means the event is created by this user, all the `Attendees` are defined in the event body like what you post above.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry pls follow the code below and have a test.

I double confirmed your code and checked the [official api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request), I noticed that what you wrote is `await GraphServiceClient(accessToken).Users["AdeleV@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com"].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event)` while the sample code is `await graphClient.Me.Calendars["{calendar-id}"].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);`, so you may need to use code `GraphServiceClient(accessToken).Users["AdeleV@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com"].Calendars["{calendar-id}"].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);` instead.

```
public void CreateEvent()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
    var clientId = "azure_ad_app_id";
    var clientSecret = "client_secret";
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    
    var @event = new Event
    {
        Subject = "Schedule From .Net",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
            Content = "Test Schedule"
        },
        Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
        {
            DateTime = "2022-07-10T12:00:00",
            TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        End = new DateTimeTimeZone
        {
            DateTime = "2022-07-10T14:00:00",
            TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        Location = new Location
        {
            DisplayName = "OR1"
        },
        Attendees = new List<Attendee>()
            {
                new Attendee
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "vinay@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com",
                        Name = "Vinay"
                    },
                    Type = AttendeeType.Required
                },
                new Attendee
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "AdeleV@yfdln.onmicrosoft.com",
                        Name = "Adelev"
                    },
                    Type = AttendeeType.Required
                }
            },
        TransactionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    };
    var res = await graphClient.Users["userId"].Calendars["{calendar-id}"].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
}
```